# How to measure the gravity component in all the three dimensions using three-axis accelerometer?

Tags: gravity, acceleration

I am reading [this](http://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/ijap/2014/372814.pdf) research paper and trying to understand how the three-axis accelerometer MMA8452Q use in this study to estimate the gravity component for three-axis i.e. $a_x$, $a_y$ and $a_z$.

**My Understanding:**

From the [data sheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MMA8452Q.pdf) of the device MMA8452Q, I understand A sensor stationary on a horizontal surface will measure 0G in X-axis and 0G in Y-axis whereas the Z-axis will measure 1G. And from the paper, the -axis acceleration was perpendicular to the ground, and stationary gravity was 1 G. Here, 1 G means $9.8 m/s^{2}$.

**Not Understood:**

After that, the paper tells the trigonometric relation to get all three components. I understand     mathematics, but not the intuition behind it, the physics behind it (By Physics I mean how the gravity is changing as we rotate any axis? How the vector component is resolved?)

I found [How do I get the total acceleration from 3 axes?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/41653/how-do-i-get-the-total-acceleration-from-3-axes?newreg=8ea2ef090140472092c6e3c6d2d8481f) but still not able to relate with my question.

I am a signal processing and ML guy and studied Physics way back, sorry for my naive doubts,Can someone help me how to measure the gravity component in all the three dimensions using a three-axis accelerometer?